# Delaying Client ID generation until the notification is acknowledged

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am crafting with the `<amp-analytics>` tag within an AMP Page und the possibility to disable the User-tracking as long the user has not given his consent to be tracked.

I had so far tried the data-consent-notification-id with the amp-analytics tag with the appropriate amp-user-notification-id, but it hasn't worked as expected. 
The user gets tracked despite the fact that he hasn't given his consent to this.
Can someone give me some hint or even an working example? 
Thank you.

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13716#issuecomment-379814502

Comment: Thank you Jay Gray, i have been already pointed to this url... it seems that its current stage is Beta-Version. As soon as i try to bind its source into our AMP script there are plenty of errors (more than 30) complaing missing this and that and plenty of errors wihtin amp engine even. Could you point me to an site where this is acctually running?

Comment: IME Google is very responsive when presented with leading-edge efforts. My advice: build a complete example that generates errors and submit to ampproject on Github. If you don't show complete example, you will not get help. Also see: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=amp-consent

Comment: As previosly pointed, the github link seems to address my current problem so I had pasted the code from https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13716 into my local AMP page and tried to run it within my AMP Extension ,  but for some reason the template is not showing up. Error: The implied layout 'CONTAINER' is not supported by tag 'amp-consent' . Some ideas?

Comment: need to see the code to be able to comment further